# 110V Light in 220V fixture?

Tags: voltage, to220

Last year I ordered [this lamp](https://aceroix.com/collections/lamps/products/infinity?variant=764115582997), which I received a few weeks later in a rather shadily packaged box sent directly from China. The box had 110V written all over it. I still like the lamp, but we are moving overseas to Europe and I'm a bit concerned that the lamp wouldn't work or worse, cause damage once installed over there. Their customer support is not responsive, unfortunately.

The label inside shows 110-220V, which indicates I should be fine.

Is there anything I should be concerned about? What's the worst that can happen if I chose to install it in a 220V fixture?

[image: inside]

Comment: The inside says 220V, their website says up to 260V. All made in china. You could replace the power supply, or trust it and it's fine or trust it and your house burns down, or buy a new lamp.

Comment: The worst that could happen is that you get a shock while trying to install the power supply, or that the power supply starts a structure fire. But since it is labeled for 220, there isn't any real reason to believe that will happen. I mean, if you were OK running it at 120, there doesn't seem to be any reason why you should worry about running it at 220, logically. If you still feel nervous, just make a point of keeping an eye on it the first time you use it, and see if it is getting excessively hot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worst that could happen is that the lamp does not have a genuine safety approval for Europe and it starts a fire, burning down your residence, killing multiple people, and invalidating your insurance, leaving your heirs litigating damages on behalf of your estate.

'Chances' are quite good that it will be functional on 220VAC, as the label indicates. Sometimes the caps get tired and may pop when they see more voltage than usual, but if it's reasonably new that probably won't happen.

Comment: The lamp has the CE label, which means the manufacturer thinks it adhers to European regulations. There are no other safety approvals needed for entry to the EU market.

Comment: @Janka, yes I know, and I have seen criminally unsafe products bearing that mark.

Comment: Yes. It's just there is no way to litigate consumers for using unsafe products with that mark. There is no mandatory safety testing in the EU.